# Dimension of a homotopy type

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is the state of knowledge about the dimension of homotopy types? By the latter I mean the minimal number which is the dimension of a topological space representing the homotopy type. The open Eilenberg–Ganea conjecture concerns 1-types. What is known for n-types?

By the dimension of a CW complex I mean the dimension of its highest cell. For general spaces one can take Lebesgue covering dimension, however the primary interest is in CW complexes.

Comment: What notion of dimension of a topological space do you have in mind?

Comment: By the dimension one can understand the Lebesgue covering dimension. I am mostly interested in spaces with a CW homotopy type. At least for the finite CW complexes the covering dimension coincides with the dimension of the highest cell.

Answer (score 12):

If you are willing to make "niceness" assumptions, assuming that the n-type is, say, nilpotent with finite fundamental group, then *the dimension, in any reasonable sense, will always be infinite*, since it will have homology in infinitely many dimensions.

The first result along these lines is due to Serre:

J.-P. Serre, Cohomologie modulo 2 des complexes d’Eilenberg–Mac Lane, Comment. Math. Helv. 27 (1953), 198–232.

I wrote a couple of papers about this back in the days:

http://www.math.ku.dk/~jg/papers/postnikov.pdf

http://www.math.ku.dk/~jg/papers/serre.pdf

where I prove that the cohomology, also as a ring, will be huge.

If you don't want to make assumptions on the fundamental group, then it is an open problem.

There are no known examples of n-types that are not $K(G,1)$s but that are homotopy equivalent to finite dimensional CW-complexes. And that there are no such examples has been stated as a conjecture by Casacuberta-Castellet in "Mislin's book of conjectures":

https://atlas.mat.ub.edu/personals/casac/articles/Mislin.pdf

Comment: In your first sentence, do you mean to say that "it will have nontrivial homology in *infinitely* many dimensions"? As it stands, the statement does not appear to imply what has been concluded from it.

Comment: @ViditNanda yes, that was obviously a confusing typo, now corrected.